# Include svg in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

I'm trying to use the climacons svgs from https://github.com/noahblon/animated-climacons.
When I copy a certain svg and paste it in my html page it works fine, but I'm trying to include it based on some logic and I cannot manage to load it.

```
<div>
  <object id="mysvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="libs/animated-climacons-master/svgs/sun.svg">
  </object> 
</div>
```

I am trying to load the climacons based on the current weather. So I am getting the weather information from a server and using that information I am trying to load a certain svg from the library. Something like:

```
<div>
  <object id="{{someIdBasedOnWeather}}" type="image/svg+xml" data="libs/animated-climacons-master/svgs/{{someStringObtainFromAService}}.svg">
  </object>
</div>
```

Can somebody please tell me how I can load these climacons in such a way?
If it helps in any way I'm using AngularJS

Comment: Can you please provide us with some more code? Would be helpful to see what you tried until now. I would like to see that logic.

Comment: How do you know what weather it is.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Apparently the folder which contained the svgs were not uploaded to the server.